# Best way to achieve CUDA Vector Diagonalization

Tags: matrix, cuda

What I want to do is feed in my m x n matrix, and in parallel, construct n square diagonal matrices for each column of the matrix, perform an operation on each square diagonal matrix, and then recombine the result. How do I do this?

So far, I start of with an m x n matrix; the result from a previous matrix computation where each element is calculated using the function y = f(g(x)).

This gives me a matrix with n column elements [f1, f2...fn] where each fn represents a column vector of height m.

From here, I want to differentiate each column of the matrix with respect to g(x). Differentiating fn(x) w.r.t. g(x) results in a square matrix with elements f'(x). Under constraint, this square matrix reduces to a Jacobian with the elements of each row along the diagonal of the square matrix, and equal to fn', all other elements equaling zero.

Hence the reason why it is necessary to construct the diagonal for each of the vector rows fn.

To do this, I take a target vector defined as A(hA x 1) which was extracted from the larger A(m x n) matrix. I then prepared a zeroed matrix defined as C(hA x hA) which will be used to hold the diagonals.

The aim is to diagonalize the vector A into a square matrix with each element of A sitting on the diagonal of C, everything else being zero.

There are probably more efficient ways to accomplish this using some pre-built routine without building a whole new kernel, but please be aware that for these purposes, this method is necessary.

The kernel code (which works) to accomplish this is shown here:

```
_cudaDiagonalizeTest << <5, 1 >> >(d_A, matrix_size.uiWA, matrix_size.uiHA, d_C, matrix_size.uiWC, matrix_size.uiHC);

__global__ void _cudaDiagonalizeTest(float *A, int wA, int hA, float *C, int wC, int hC)
{
    int ix, iy, idx;

    ix = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    iy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    idx = iy * wA + ix;

    C[idx * (wC + 1)] = A[idx];

}
```

I am a bit suspicious that this is a very naive approach to a solution and was wondering if someone could give an example of how I could do the same using

a) reduction

b) thrust

For vectors of large row size, I would like to be able to use the GPU's multithreading capabilities to chunk the task into small jobs, and combine each result at the end with __syncthreads().

The picture below shows what the desired result is.

I have read [NVIDIA's article on reduction](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.download.nvidia.com%2Fcompute%2Fcuda%2F1.1-Beta%2Fx86_website%2Fprojects%2Freduction%2Fdoc%2Freduction.pdf&ei=BQVrVbaDKuGp7AawxYGgCw&usg=AFQjCNFZmgdihbG17glvRmF-zPHfmUR4Aw), but did not manage to achieve the desired results.

Any assistance or explanation would be very much welcomed.

[image]
Thanks.

[image]

Matrix A is the target with 4 columns. I want to take each column, and copy its elements into Matrix B as a diagonal, iterating through each column.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly what you're looking for. Could you please include a sample input and desired output? I don't see how reduction applies to this problem.

Comment: Are you really sure you need to do this at all? If you have a purely diagonal matrix, the best way to store and use it is as you already have it - as a diagonal array. You will use up a lot of memory, a lot of memory bandwidth and a lot of flops just loading and storing zeros, usually for no good reason

Comment: The diagonalization of the afformentioned vector row is only a small step in a larger operation. What I am attempting is to diagonalize each row of a m x n matrix in parallel, perform computations with these n diagonalized square matrices (there are n rows in the m x n matrix and hence n diagonalized square matrices after having diagonalized each one), and then sum the results of the computation back together again. All this must be done in the kernel. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You keep talking about "diagonalisation", but the operation you are doing in code is *constructing* a diagonal matrix from a vector. The are not the same thing. What problem are you actually trying to solve here? Even if you  are performing some sort of linear transformation to a general matrix to reduce it to diagonal form, my previous remarks hold true. There are *enormous* performance and implementation advantages to simply storing the diagonal matrix as a vector and reimplementing whatever algebras you need to exploit the diagonal property

Comment: Yes. You are right. I am constructing diagonal matrices from each row of an m x n matrix. Each of these rows contains elements y = f(g(x)). I am constructing a new set of matrices with elements y' =  f'(g(x)) w.r.t. g(x) (differential of each row of the m x n matrix). In otherwords, I am attempting to calculate the Jacobian of each row in the matrix m x n. This is esentially an m x m matrix with each element of the original vector on the diagonal and a trace equal to the sum of all elements in the row. If you can think of a better way of doing this, Iam willing to take it into consideration.

Comment: you should edit your question so that it contains your "ultimate goal" as well as how you calculate the differentials. give input and desired output and all the intermediate steps for a simple example (e.g. n=5, m=4)

Comment: I made adjustments to my previous post.

Comment: Would it be correct to say all you ultimately want to do is to take the elements of an array (with stride 1), and copy them to another array with stride N?

Comment: If by elements, you mean vectors, and if by array, you mean matrix, then yes. I want to take each column of an m x n matrix, and put each element of this column along the diagonal of a new square matrix. I want to do this in the most efficient way possible. The code above shows how I construct a diagonal square matrix from the original vector array. But, I am not sure if it is the most effective way to do it.

Comment: Are you sure your sample kernel is really doing that then? Anyways, let me try again to guess what you mean: you want to copy `A(x,y)` to `C(x,x+y)`, where `M(x,y)` means the entry of `M` in the `x`-th row and `y`-th column? (using 0-based indices) and... maybe filling in the rest of `C` with zeroes? Or maybe you mean to copy `A(x,y)` to `C(x, (x+y) mod N)`, where `N` is the number of columns of `C`?

Comment: Yes. this is what I mean. I have included an image in the original post to illustrate that the sample code does achieve what I want. On the left, I have a column vector of 5 x 1. On the right I have a 5 x 5 square matrix with the elements along the diagonal, and everything else zeroed. The memory to hold the resulting square matrix is already zeroed upon initialization. I simply have to copy the elements to the correct location. Everything works well, i just want to know if there is a more efficient way to do it, and if so, what?

Comment: What I want to do is feed in my m x n matrix, and in parallel, perform several diagonalization constructions as shown above, perform an operation on each square diagonal matrix, and then recombine the result. How do I do this?

Comment: I'd still appreciate a small, numerical example to explain the intermediate steps ...

Comment: Refer to the second image for a clearer picture. Matrix A is a smaller 5 x 4 matrix (5 rows, 4 columns). Matrix B is a larger 5 x 20 matrix (5 rows, 20 columns). I want to take each of the 4 columns of Matrix A  (each one being a vector of height 5) and lay out its elements into a diagonal. Each diagonal construction would produce a 5 x 5 matrix which would then fit into the larger 5 x 20 Matrix B. I want to do this in parallel using CUDA. Please refer to the image posted at the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a simple example based on thrust. It uses column-major order to store the matrices in a `thrust::device_vector`. It should scale well with larger row/column counts.

Another approach could be based off the [thrust `strided_range` example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/strided_range.cu).

This example does what you want (fill the diagonals based on the input vector). However, depending on how you proceed with the resulting matrix to your "Differentiating" step, it might still be worth investigating if a sparse storage (without all the zero entries) is possible, since this will reduce memory consumption and ease iterating.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/scatter.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <iostream>


template<typename V>
void print_matrix(const V& mat, int rows, int cols)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
   {
     for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
     {
      std::cout << mat[i + j*rows] << "\t";
     }
     std::cout << std::endl;
   }
}

struct diag_index : public thrust::unary_function<int,int>
{
  diag_index(int rows) : rows(rows){}

  __host__ __device__
  int operator()(const int index) const
  {
      return (index*rows + (index%rows));
  }

  const int rows;
};

int main()
{
  const int rows = 5; 
  const int cols = 4;

  // allocate memory and fill with demo data
  // we use column-major order
  thrust::device_vector<int> A(rows*cols);
  thrust::sequence(A.begin(), A.end());

  thrust::device_vector<int> B(rows*rows*cols, 0);

  // fill diagonal matrix
  thrust::scatter(A.begin(), A.end(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),diag_index(rows)), B.begin());

  print_matrix(A, rows, cols);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  print_matrix(B, rows, rows*cols);
  return 0;
}
```

This example will output:

```
0    5    10    15    
1    6    11    16    
2    7    12    17    
3    8    13    18    
4    9    14    19    

0    0    0    0    0    5    0    0    0    0    10    0    0    0    0    15    0    0    0    0    
0    1    0    0    0    0    6    0    0    0    0    11    0    0    0    0    16    0    0    0    
0    0    2    0    0    0    0    7    0    0    0    0    12    0    0    0    0    17    0    0    
0    0    0    3    0    0    0    0    8    0    0    0    0    13    0    0    0    0    18    0    
0    0    0    0    4    0    0    0    0    9    0    0    0    0    14    0    0    0    0    19
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using thrust?

Comment: I figured the equivalent out, and posted it as an alternative answer.

Answer (score -1):

An alternate answer that does not use thrust is as follows:

```
_cudaMatrixTest << <5, 5 >> >(d_A, matrix_size.uiWA, matrix_size.uiHA, d_C, matrix_size.uiWC, matrix_size.uiHC);

__global__ void _cudaMatrixTest(float *A, int wA, int hA, float *C, int wC, int hC)
{
    int ix, iy, idx;

    ix = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    iy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    idx = iy * wA + ix;

    C[idx * wC + (idx % wC)] = A[threadIdx.x * wA + (ix / wC)];
}
```

where d_A is

```
0    5    10    15    
1    6    11    16    
2    7    12    17    
3    8    13    18    
4    9    14    19
```

Both answers are viable solutions. The question is, which is better/faster?

Comment: Your code seems pretty odd.  You're launching 1D threadblocks and grid, so `iy` will always be 0, also, you are launching a total of 25 threads, but you only have 20 locations to populate.

Comment: you are correct. it is actually a 5 x 5 not a 5 x 4 as the matrix illustrates. Also, iy doesn't have to be there. just a quick job really, but it works. I just didn't clean up the code.